# ASP.NET: How to display a jQuery Dialog after Page Response.Redirect?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, redirect, dialog, modal-dialog

Is it possible to show a jQuery Modal Dialog after a Page Redirect (Full Postback) ?

I have a page:

MyEditForm.aspx/EditId=0

In that page there is a form and a SAVE button, when I click the SAVE button I want to show a jQuery Modal Dialog giving the users some options but I want to show that dialog after I redirect the user to this page:

MyEditForm.aspx/EditId=500

It's the same page but with (EditId=500)

Here's my code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("jQuery(document).ready(function () {");
sb.Append("  jQuery(function() { ");
sb.Append("    jQuery('#MyDivID').dialog({");
sb.Append("      width: 350, autoOpen: true, modal: true);
sb.Append("    });");
sb.Append("  });");
sb.Append("});");

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "MyDialogScript", sb.ToString(), true);

Response.Redirect("~/MyEditForm.aspx/EditId=" + NewRecordId, false);
```

If I don't use Response.Redirect the Dialog works fine but I won't be able to redirect the user to the page with the new ID, how can I solve this?

Comment: Does it necessarily need to be a modal popup, or have you considered just having a panel that is only shown if a condition is met (like a non-zero value in `EditId`)?

Comment: @TiesonT. Thanks for the suggestions,  Yes it has to be a modal popup and adding a condition like non-zero value would not work because I only want it to appear just one time after I click the SAVE button.

Answer (score 2):

Move the following code into the Page_Load method and modify like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    int editId=0;
    if(Request["EditId"]!=null and Int32.TryParse(Request["EditId"], out editId)){
       if(editId>0){
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          sb.Append("jQuery(document).ready(function () {");
          sb.Append("  jQuery(function() { ");
          sb.Append("    jQuery('#MyDivID').dialog({");
          sb.Append("      width: 350, autoOpen: true, modal: true);
          sb.Append("    });");
          sb.Append("  });");
          sb.Append("});");
          Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "MyDialogScript", sb.ToString(), true);
       }
    }
}
```

and use the `Respon.Redirect` in the Save button click handler.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I forgot to mention that I only want to show the dialog only Once after I click the SAVE button because when I enter that page in EDIT mode (ie EditId > 0) I don't want to show the dialog at all.

Comment: In that case I would suggest you to add another querystring into the url to specify that the redirect has happened from the save button. i.e. Response.Redirect("~/MyEditForm.aspx?Saved=1&EditId=" + NewRecordId, false); and check for the presence of 'Saved' quesrystring